# How do I selectively scrape hrefs from div tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape URLS from a news website. Specifically, they are the URLs of news articles listed in the search results for a specific search term.

I'm new to BeautifulSoup, and I don't know how to selectively scrape just the hrefs that take me to an article (when I try to scrape for children hrefs in div tags, I just get an empty set, and when I scrape a tags, I get way more URLs than I want.

Any thoughts?

Here's a link to the webpage:
https://www.thenational.ae/search?q=aramco

Here's the code I'm using.

```
import requests, random, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.thenational.ae/search?q=aramco"
webpage = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(webpage.text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all('h1'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the structure of the HTML. From the structure, you can see that the `hrefs` you need are childrens of same div with class `small-article-desc`. So basically you do it this way:

```
import requests, random, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.thenational.ae/search?q=aramco"
webpage = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(webpage.text, "html.parser")
for div in soup.find_all('div', {"class": "small-article-desc"}):
    a = div.find_all('a')
    print(a[0].get('href'))
```